# error when convert project from vc 6.0 to vc 2010

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6, visual-c++-2010

i have successfully compile and build  c/c++ project on visual c++ 6.0 to dll .But when i convert to visual c++ 2010 on windwos 7 64bit os it appear many error .source code is

```
typedef  struct {                                   
     int               _entID          ; /* Entity ID                   */
     int               _recID          ; /* Recode No.                  */
     int               _Nmbr           ; /* 画像番号          0020:0013 */
     int               _Clmns          ; /* マトリクス X      0028:0011 */
     int               _Rws            ; /* マトリクス Y      0028:0010 */
     int               _ImagCnt        ; /* 複数フレーム数    0028:0008 */
     char              _Type[ 68 ]     ; /* 画像タイプ        0008:0008 */
     char              _cUID[ 68 ]     ; /* クラス UID        0004:1510 */
     char              _sUID[ 68 ]     ; /* SOP    UID        0008:0018 */
     char              _pathNm[ 128 ]  ;

     char             *_sptr           ;*****error at line*****
     int               _xsiz           ;//
     int               _ysiz           ; /*    "         Y サイズ       */
                                         /*                       @2.01 */
   char              _SpcSet[ 20 ]   ; /* Specific Char     0008:0005 */
                                         /*                       @2.30 */
     char              _SpcSet[ 64 ]   ; /* Specific Char     0008:0005 */
     }                 DDIR_IMAG_INF   ; /*                             */'
```

when build on vc 2010 it appear many similar error like this:
Error   1   d:\dxr-mls\program\dicm_dir_tool.dll\source\dicm_dir_tool\include\dicm_dir_tool_dll.h   error C2059: syntax error : ';' 
visual c++ 6.0 project is ansii project with comment is japanese , use some dll and library of windows system ,was build successful in windows xp 32 bit 
help me

Comment: This is a good object lesson in why you should always give your variables **descriptive names**. If *you* don't know what the heck those variables are used for, then *we certainly* don't.

Comment: As far as solving your problem, it might be helpful to [read the documentation for the compiler error you're receiving](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8xe60cf(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: What is the tick after the last comment for? Is this ignored by the VC6 compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8xe60cf(v=vs.100).aspx
Some may apply to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The strings `*_sptr` and `*_uptr` appear to be "magic" pointer types in Visual C++. I've searched MSDN and Google and can't find a reference but it looks like you simply can't have a variable named `_sptr`. Based on [this bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/229419/compile-error-c2088-on-variable-name-broke-in-sp1) they may be reserved identifiers.

Note that you also have two fields with the same name: `_SpcSet`